# PWSH - ValidateScript as reference to external ps1 script

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, powershell-core

I would like to validate my powershell function parameters with ValidateScript. Example

```
param (
        [ValidateScript({
                $response = (Invoke-webrequest -URI $_)
                if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
                    throw "  ❌  API Nedpoint $($_) is not reachable"
                }
                
                return $true
            })]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$buildURL
    )
```

This is valid code, but I would prefere to reference external ps1 file like

```
param (
        [ValidateScript(.\Validate-site.ps1)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$buildURL
    )
```

Which what I found is not supported like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validatescript-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.4

If so, do you have some alternative way to validate your input for pwsh functions? Please share your code examples, or some validations which you would like to show off and are not so basic as mine.

Comment: what is stopping you from using a scriptblock that calls your external file? `[ValidateScript({ & "path\to\Validate-site.ps1" })]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke an external script with `ValidateScript` without a problem, but you must use a script block as argument for your validation. You can invoke it then with the [Call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```bash
[ValidateScript({ & "path\to\Validate-site.ps1" })]
```

You were asking for examples so here is one that does not use [`ValidateScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validatescript-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.3) and uses a custom class that inherits from [`ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validateenumeratedargumentsattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) instead:

```bash
class ValidateUri : System.Management.Automation.ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute {
    [void] ValidateElement([object] $Object) {
        $invokeWebRequestSplat = @{
            UseBasicParsing = $true
            Method          = 'Head'
            Uri             = $Object
        }

        try {
            $response = Invoke-WebRequest @invokeWebRequestSplat
            if($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
                throw [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException]::new(
                    "  ❌  API Nedpoint $($Object) is not reachable")
            }
        }
        catch {
            # Different error can go here
            throw [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException]::new(
                "  ❌  API Nedpoint $($Object) is not reachable")
        }
    }
}

function Test-ValidateUri {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateUri()]
        [string] $Uri
    )

    $PSBoundParameters
}

Test-ValidateUri google.com
Test-ValidateUri doesnotexist.xyz
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago, great tip to invoke it with &. 

The example is nice alternative, but for the record of others I could not justify use of classes in here, it brings to the game all the hassle like 

- Encapsulation
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism
- Statefulness

It's all about use-cases, but I prefere to script things out not and stay away from OOP in favor of simplicity.

Comment: I should add that too to my answer, my bad @Thomas I'll add it now

Comment: @Thomas added. btw, recommendation, use `-Method 'Head'` as I'm showing in my answer. If someone passes a download link to your function, the validation script would attempt to download it otherwise making your validation extremely slow ;)